# Create a class with a package in a Scala Ammonite Script

Tags: scala, ammonite

I have written the following scala script in ammonite shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env amm
@main
def main() = {
    val p = Person("foo")
}

case class Person(name: String)
```

This compiles and works fine. But I need the class Person to be in a package called `com.foo`

If I try

```
#!/usr/bin/env amm
@main
def main() = {
    val p = Person("foo")
}

package com.foo {
  case class Person(name: String)
}
```

Now I get a syntax error which is like

```
Syntax Error: End:7:1 ..."package co"
package com.foo {
```

I wonder how can I specify the namespace for my case class. Since its a script, I would like to keep everything in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the script content is wrapped by Ammonite in an object (to have top-level statements and definitions), you cannot use `package`. But you can namespace your class by defining it in a nested object:

```
object com {
  object foo {
    case class Person(name: String)
  }
}

@main
def main() = {
  val p = com.foo.Person("foo")
}
```

If you will later import this script in another one, you will also use this namespace (without the wrapping):

```
import $file.firstScript, firstScript._

println(com.foo.Person("Bob"))
```

Comment: This technique is ok, but what about is I have to pass a full class name to Jython, or to dynamically create an object given its full class name?